# Getting Automatic MODIS HDF Files 2003-2018 by Shell Script

Tags: modis, linux, download

```
#!/bin/bash
# This Script is for getting Automatic HDF Files  
# Product MODIS MYD11A2 Data From web https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/  
# Change Login And Passwords User registred on Earthdata
# This example can download 4 Tiles MODIS like 
# h11v11 h11v12 h12v11 h12v12
# For me exclude xml files.
#
chmod 0600 ~/.netrc
touch ~/.netrc
echo "machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login XXX password XXXX" > ~/.netrc

touch ~/.urs_cookies


    for year in $(seq -w 2003 2018)
    do
        for mes in $(seq -w 01 12)
        do
            for dia in $(seq -w 1 31)
            do

    fecha=$year.$mes.$dia
    wget -q --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject "index.html*" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/$fecha/ -O /dev/stdout | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="href="}{print $2}' |gawk  -v fecha=$fecha 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print "wget -nc --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject \"index.html*\" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/"fecha"/"$2}'|grep h11v11|grep -v jpg|grep -v xml |sh
    wget -q --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject "index.html*" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/$fecha/ -O /dev/stdout | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="href="}{print $2}' |gawk  -v fecha=$fecha 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print "wget -nc --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject \"index.html*\" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/"fecha"/"$2}'|grep h11v12|grep -v jpg|grep -v xml |sh
    wget -q --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject "index.html*" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/$fecha/ -O /dev/stdout | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="href="}{print $2}' |gawk  -v fecha=$fecha 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print "wget -nc --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject \"index.html*\" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/"fecha"/"$2}'|grep h12v11|grep -v jpg|grep -v xml |sh
    wget -q --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject "index.html*" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/$fecha/ -O /dev/stdout | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="href="}{print $2}' |gawk  -v fecha=$fecha 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{print "wget -nc --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --reject \"index.html*\" http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLA/MYD11A2.006/"fecha"/"$2}'|grep h12v12|grep -v jpg|grep -v xml |sh
            done
        done
    done
```

Comment: This is an example of a "wall of code" post. They are often downvoted because no attempt has been made to describe the situation, the task, the intended approach, or to describe the problem. Please [Edit] the question to be a Question.

Comment: This is not a question.  Nevertheless, I have provided an answer.  I've no idea if it is the answer to the question, as I don't know what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell:

```
cd /path/to/script/directory
vi script_file_name
```

In vi:

```
:%s/XXXX/your_password/
:%s/XXX/your_login_name/
:wq
```

In the shell:

```
./script_file_name
```

Comment: Yes  Son Of the Beach!!! This Script is my contributions. Is not a Questions is a Solutions... Regards!!